# Dropzone : Uncaught Error: No URL provided

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropzone.js

I have following form:

```
<form class="block-center" id="pdfForm" method="POST" action="form_threatment.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" style="margin-top: 30px;">    
  <div class="form-group push-50-t col-md-12">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="form-material form-material-primary">    
        <div class="dropzone dropzone-previews" id="pdfFile">
        </div>    
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>    
</div>

<div class="form-group push-50-t col-md-6">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="form-material form-material-primary">                               
      <input class="form-control" name="first_name" type="text" id="first_name" />
      <label for="first_name"><span class="asterix">*</span> Prénom : </label>                      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I include dropzone.js library like this :

```
<script src="assets/js/dropzone.js"></script>
```

And my own dropzone myDropzone.js :

```
<script src="assets/js/myDropzone.js"></script>
```

In the `myDropzone.js` file I have configured the div#pdfFile this way :

```
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

$(document).ready(function() {      

    Dropzone.options.pdfFile = {
        // url does not has to be written if we have wrote action in the form tag but i have mentioned here just for convenience sake 
        url: 'form_threatment.php',
        acceptedFiles: '.pdf',
        maxFilesize: 20,
        addRemoveLinks: true,
        autoProcessQueue: false, // this is important as you dont want form to be submitted unless you have clicked the submit button
        uploadMultiple: false,
        autoDiscover: false,
        paramName: 'pdf', // this is optional Like this one will get accessed in php by writing $_FILE['pic'] // if you dont specify it then by default it taked 'file' as paramName eg: $_FILE['file'] 
        previewsContainer: '#pdfFile', // we specify on which div id we must show the files
        clickable: false, // this tells that the dropzone will not be clickable . we have to do it because v dont want the whole form to be clickable 

        accept: function(file, done) {
            console.log("uploaded");
            done();
        },
        error: function(file, msg){
            alert(msg);
        },
        init: function() {
            var myDropzone = this;

            // #submit-all it the id of the submit button
            $("#submit-all").on("click", function(e) {
                var files = $('#pdfFile').get(0).dropzone.getAcceptedFiles();
                console.log(myDropzone);
                console.log(files);
                //e.preventDefault();
                //e.stopPropagation();
                myDropzone.processQueue(); // this will submit your form to the specified action path
                // after this, your whole form will get submitted with all the inputs + your files and the php code will remain as usual 
                //REMEMBER you DON'T have to call ajax or anything by yourself, dropzone will take care of that

            });                                             
        }
    };
    Dropzone.options.pdfFile.init();
});
```

When loading the page, I get the error:

> Uncaught Error: No URL provided.

Earlier, I had modified the dropzone.js file to setup the Dropzone options, but I reset the **dropzone.js** library file and decided to setup the options in **myDropzone.js** file.

When the options were set up in the **dropzone.js** file, I had no error but after I reset these, and setup them in **myDropzone.js**, I had this error, which makes me believe **the options aren't initialized** in **myDropzone.js**.

Fact is, the init() function works properly when I click on the **#submit-all button**.

Any idea on how to solve the problem please?

---

Okay, I solved the :

> Uncaught Error: No URL provided.

by deleting it.

Now, when I submit, I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: myDropzone.processQueue is not a function

in the init() function.

**Edit:**

I solved the last previous error, by deleting the processQueue function, and blocking the *Validate* button of my upload page, until the PDF has not been uploaded succesfully.
I know it's an ugly hack, but I didn't figure out another way to do it.

Comment: `Uncaught Error: No URL provided` - any indication which line of code this error is on?

Comment: It raises on line 440 of dropzone.js which is : `if (!this.options.url) {
        throw new Error("No URL provided.");
      }`
This is in the function `function Dropzone(element, options)` of the dropzone.js library.
Should I import **myDropzone.js** before **dropzone.js** ?

Comment: definitely do not reverse the order of those two files - you certainly don't seem to set any `options.url` so it stands to reason you get that error

Comment: I provided the url in myDropzone.js: `url: 'form_threatment.php'`, + the form action is `form_threatment.php` too.

Comment: no, that's `options.pdfFile.url`

Comment: I don't understand what's the difference, is `options.url` is the defaultOptions of Dropzone ? Isn't it overrided when I give an URL to a specific dropzone ?

Comment: I haven't looked into the source code of dropzone.js, so I'm only guessing based on the error and your code

Comment: Okay. **dropzone.js** library file defines the URL of the dropzone this way : `Dropzone.prototype.defaultOptions = {
      url: null,  [...]   };`

But it would be stupid to change the URL in this file, because if I update the dropzone library, I'll have to reconfigure it once again..

Comment: just read the documentation - seems you're doing things correctly - sorry for engaging in meaningless conversation :p

Comment: Haha no problem :p
I just can't get why the options are ignored when you define them outside of the dropzone.js file...

Answer (score 1):

Don't put your dropzone code inside jquery `$(document).ready(function(){ });`

Comment: Why would it solve my problem ? Is it forbidden to wrap this in the `ready()` event ?

Answer (score 0):

I think of 3 things :
Your main dropzone element (where you DROP) is #pdfForm
And you want the previews in #pdfFiles. That said :

1) code must be `Dropzone.options.pdfForm` and not `Dropzone.options.pdfFile`

2) `Dropzone.options.pdfForm` is a right syntax when autodiscover is let to true (default). But if tou want autodiscover to false, you might try :
`var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#pdfForm", { url: "form_threatment.php", other options... // JS : Dropzone class` or
`$("#pdfForm").dropzone({ url: "form_threatment.php", other options... // JS : jquery style`

3) If you specify "form_threatment.php" in JS, you don't have to do it in HTML. Then you can remove action="form_threatment.php" from the form

see also my other answer for possible problems with jQuery version 3 if you decide to use autodiscover=true (defalut) : [Why is my dropzone javascript form not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19006939/why-is-my-dropzone-javascript-form-not-working/40421784#40421784)

Comment: Already did all of this.. But didn't solve the problem. I figured out an ugly work around for the moment lol.

Answer (score 0):

After trying all proposals, I actually solved this doing an ugly work-around in my `treatment_form.php` :

I do 2 times threatment :

1. When receiving the PDF, I check everything is fine and I upload it to my server.
2. When the user submits the form, I verify the rest of the information in the form, and threat them knowing that the PDF has been uploaded.